# I am getting a syntax error with my mysql query code below

Tags: php, mysql

Variable declaration:-

```
$firstname=""; 
$surname ="";
$id ="";
$faculty_of_study= "";
$enrolled_course ="";
$gender ="";
$password= "";
$telephone_no="";
$email_address=""; 
$sql="";

$firstname = addslashes($_POST["firstname"]);
$surname = addslashes($_POST["surname"]);
$id = addslashes($_POST["id"]); 
$faculty_of_study = addslashes($_POST["faculty_of_study"]);
$enrolled_course = addslashes($_POST["enrolled_course"]);
$gender = addslashes($_POST["gender"]);
$password = addslashes($_POST["password"]);
$telephone_no = addslashes($_POST["telephone_no"]);
$email_address = addslashes($_POST["email_address"]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, surname, id,faculty_of_study, enrolled_course, gender, password, telephone_no, email_address); VALUES ("$firstname", "$surname", "$id", "$faculty_of_study",  "$enrolled_course", "$gender","$password", "$telephone_no", "$email_address")";
```

> syntax error  unexpected '$firstname' (T_VARIABLE) on line 21

Comment: `email_address);` => remove semicolon `;`

Comment: `"$firstname"` etc: => `'$firstname'` etc (single quoteds instead of doubles)

Comment: Not related to the problem, but ***never*** use `addslashes` for database data; it does not offer any sort of real protection. `mysql_real_escape_string` would at least be better.

Comment: ...but not much better. See prepared statements,

Comment: people are not interested in marking the answer. Wastage of effort and time.Deleting my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, surname, id,   
 faculty_of_study, enrolled_course, gender, password, telephone_no, 
email_address) VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$id',  
'$faculty_of_study',
'$enrolled_course', '$gender','$password', '$telephone_no','$email_address')";
```

Comment: See prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (firstname, surname, id,faculty_of_study, enrolled_course, gender, password, telephone_no, email_address) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$surname."', '".$id."', '".$faculty_of_study."',  '".$enrolled_course."', '".$gender."','".$password."', '".$telephone_no."', '".$email_address."')";
```

and remove semicolon before `VALUES`.